# Help define a Web Applications Stack Exchange site

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, site-proposal

Given [the commotion around](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39615/superuser-website-applications-policy) 'banning' web-apps from Super User and that [Jeff already suggested it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42373/what-sites-are-currently-missing-from-the-trilogy) as a 'new' Trilogy site, I would like to ask for some [help defining the proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6023/proposal-for-a-web-applications-site) for a Web Applications Stack Exchange site.

Though I've made a proposal on meta.stackexchange.com, I think that not everyone interested in this site is actually looking on MSE, so therefore this shameless plug! If you want this site: put your votes and comments where your mouth is!

From MSE:

> **The topic**
>
> This site will be aimed at **questions
>   on using web applications**. The first
>   that come to mind (and which are
>   explicitly banned from SU) are
>   **Facebook, Twitter and Wordpress**. Though off course **Google Apps or
>   Gmail** and other web apps would
>   suffice.
>
> ---
>
> **Target Audience**
>
> *People who have questions about using **web apps***
>
> Personally I would love this site to
>   replace the current help/support
>   forums of the above named sites. But
>   excluding the following:
>
> - This site should not be aimed at programmers, who want to program a web
>     app, [we have Stack Overflow for
>     that.](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)
> - I'm not sure if intranet and SaaS applications would be suited or if
>     that's more [a target of Server
>     Fault.](https://serverfault.com/faq)
> - It's also not for web designers with questions about CSS, HTML, web design
>     and email design problems. [They
>     should go to DocType.](http://doctype.com/about)
>
> ---
>
> **On-topic questions**
>
> - [Bloggers, how do you deal with spam?](https://superuser.com/questions/47/bloggers-how-do-you-deal-with-spam)
> - [How do I make Facebook block a friend’s Mafia Wars updates?](https://superuser.com/questions/16298/how-do-i-make-facebook-block-a-friends-mafia-wars-updates-closed)
> - [Facebook: Upload problem with the (java) photo uploader](https://superuser.com/questions/4366/facebook-upload-problem-with-the-java-photo-uploader-closed)
> - [How do I download photos tagged of me from Facebook?](https://superuser.com/questions/50854/how-do-i-download-photos-tagged-of-me-from-facebook-closed)
> - [How do I search someone’s tweets?](https://superuser.com/questions/6562/how-do-i-search-someones-tweets-closed)
> - [Can I auto-forward Gmail to multiple addresses?](https://superuser.com/questions/15034/can-i-auto-forward-gmail-to-multiple-addresses-closed)
>
> ---
>
> **Off-topic questions**
>
> - [Twitter image encoding challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891643/twitter-image-encoding-challenge) (belongs on Stack
>     Overflow)
> - [Where are the best resources for learning how to create Drupal Themes
>     from a visual design?](http://doctype.com/where-best-resources-learning-create-drupal-themes-from-visual-design) (belongs on
>     DocType)
> - What's your favorite Facebook game?, (subjective, [though that's not always
>     a problem](https://superuser.com/questions/1241/what-are-some-must-have-windows-programs))
> - Who should I follow on Twitter?, (also subjective, though the answer is
>     Britney or Ashton)
> - What is a good hosting solution in Elbonian? (too localized as opposed to
>     [a general version](https://superuser.com/questions/94956/where-should-i-host-my-simple-website-closed))
> - [With a web os, can the browser still be in the device by itself?](https://superuser.com/questions/111544/web-based-operating-system)
>     (not a real question)
> - Where can I download ....... (fill in warez, movies or anything illegal)?

I would love to get some feedback on the following discussion points:

There might be a problem with the scope of this site.

- As to [quote Jeff Atwood:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39615/superuser-website-applications-policy/39618#39618)

  > such a site would be ridiculously
  >   broad -- "ask questions here about ..
  >   uh .. any website on the internet!!"
  >   So I hope you can see why we don't
  >   want this for SU which is already
  >   quite broad in scope.
- Perhaps the current scope (any question on any site) might be a little ambitious, I'm sure we will find a compromise somewhere.

There's also a grey-area, considering things like:

- Where's the border between asking how to put in some code for Google Analytics on your Wordpress blog and changing the CSS layout? The first would fit this site, the other DocType or StackOverflow if it required some programming.
- Chrome OS, is it a real OS like Windows/OSX and does it belong on Super User? Or is it one large web app and belongs it on this site?
- Browsers vs web apps, some questions might be about integration of specific web apps into the browser. Is this a browser or a web apps question or perhaps both?
- Desktop/Adobe Air apps, things like TweetDeck and Adobe Air or Mozilla's Prism create a grey area around desktop and web apps. I would say these are on-topic here and make them off-topic for Super User.
- SEO and website optimization, given that people will ask questions about using a website, it might lead to people also wanting to ask questions related to managing their website. I would consider these off-topic, since this would be more for creators rather than users of websites. Plus there are already several proposals for these kind of topics, which would suit the questions better.

So any suggestions on making the distinction clear would be great!

**Oh and please propose a name as well!**

### For anyone interested: [help commit to the proposal!](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications?referrer=M9Gwiotwfxw1)

Comment: PageNotFound.com?

Comment: What about [AwSnap.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6023/proposal-for-a-web-applications-site/6045#6045)?

Answer (score 2):

Good definition in general, I think.

About the server fault dilemma, we have to think with SF main line:

> Server Fault is for system
>   administrators and IT professionals,
>   people who manage or maintain
>   computers in a professional capacity.
>   If you are in charge of ...
>
> - servers
> - networks
> - many desktop PCs (other than your own)
>
> ... then you're in the right place to
>   ask your question! Well, as long as
>   the question is about your servers,
>   your networks, or desktops you
>   support, anyway.

For SF, I think the main question before asking is "who are you?", "what is your job?".

---

A bit of my opinion on the grey areas:

> - Where's the border between asking how to put in some code for Google
>     Analytics on your Wordpress blog and
>     changing the CSS layout? The first
>     would fit this site, the other DocType
>     or StackOverflow if it required some
>     programming.

Like the initial sentence, this site is for questions about *using* web apps. Putting some code for Google, we can consider it's about using Google analytics, but that's mostly all. Rest is indeed more for website creation/edition, and should be redirected somewhere else.

> - Chrome OS, is it a real OS like Windows/OSX and does it belong on
>     Super User? Or is it one large web app
>     and belongs it on this site?

Like currently with SU: if the issue is about installing and maintaining the system (recognizing hardware, installing drivers, setting Chrome, it is for SU. Anything which happens on a web app accessed from Chrome OS would be for this other site.

> - Browsers vs web apps, some questions might be about integration of specific
>     web apps into the browser. Is this a
>     browser or a web apps question or
>     perhaps both?

Depends indeed on the question. If the issue is about installing it, or what exists to install, SU. If it's about using it, and it requires setting something on a distant server, this site.

> - Desktop/Adobe Air apps, things like TweetDeck and Adobe Air or Mozilla's
>     Prism create a grey area around
>     desktop and web apps. I would say
>     these are on-topic here and make them
>     off-topic for Super User.

As far as I'm concerned, as a user, an Adobe Air application is something I launch from my computer, without caring about the connection (Balsamiq Mockups, for example). It is delivered and updated through a quite automatic online system, but as a user, all I see is a desktop application.

> - SEO and website optimization, given that people will ask questions about
>     using a website, it might lead to
>     people also wanting to ask questions
>     related to managing their website. I
>     would consider these off-topic, since
>     this would be more for creators rather
>     than users of websites. Plus there are
>     already several proposals for these
>     kind of topics, which would suit the
>     questions better.

Same point here, I think the key to keep the scope is the *using*. Managing server is more for SF, optimizing is more for SO or doctype.

---

For names, I think we can take inspiration from the usual error codes (though seeing them for an actual webpage feels weird):

- [Client errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error)

  - 404notfound.com
  - requesttimeout.com
- [Server errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error)

  - serviceunavailable.com

Comment: Thanks for the good comments, it would help if the site would have multiple cross-site moderators, who know what questions belong where and transfer them appropriately. And I like your name suggestions!

Answer (score -1):

This site has some problems as defined. Anything where asking about functionality on "any website on earth" is a valid question ... is going to be *utter freaking chaos*.

> - Bloggers, how do you deal with spam?
> - How do I make Facebook block a friend’s Mafia Wars updates?
> - Facebook: Upload problem with the (java) photo uploader
> - How do I download photos tagged of me from Facebook?
> - How do I search someone’s tweets?
> - Can I auto-forward Gmail to multiple addresses?

Did you notice that: (3) of these questions are about Facebook? Hmm?

I think we should scope it. **Probably just to Facebook** since they're by far the most dominant and popular site, and apparently growing by the size of Albania every second.

I mean, we could do "Facebook and Twitter and GMail!" but.. where does it end? Why aren't we including, say, NewsVine and Reddit and ESPN and .. my god, the list is *endless*.

So, stick to Facebook. We can cover both API and power user functionality in the same site.

Comment: The list of installable programs and hardware combinations is "endless" as well. That doesn't prevent SU from running correctly with all these possibilities.

Comment: Making a site only for Facebook is likely to answer 80% of questions with links to their help center, for the user questions. The point of a wider site is like for the rest of the trilogy, to cover also smaller cases, for which you won't find an instant answer on a dedicated help center. It would be like making a ServerFault site where only Exchange questions could go.

Comment: I simply checked for Super User questions on websites and used Facebook as an example. There isn't that much complex functionality in Facebook on a user level, not a programmer!

Comment: Also I didn't exclude sites like Reddit and ESPN, I simply haven't come across any at Super User yet.

Comment: What's the point in opening a SE site only for facebook? Those guys have their support forum already. It'll end up the same like super user. People will ask questions about other sites and they will get closed. This site is just so these questions can stay open, or get migrated there!

Comment: Like @Ivo also mentions [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6023/proposal-for-a-web-applications-site/6045#6045): "SO shows you can have multiple, distinct programming languages on one site and gain a much larger community. The same goes for websites."

Comment: It will be the new trashcan for the Trilogy!