# Showing the yes-nos is bias

Tags: feature-request, voting, area-51

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Voting on Area51 is very biased](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52266/voting-on-area51-is-very-biased)

Showing the yes-nos is bias. They should be hidden for an unbiased result. ([In Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/))

Comment: I agree even on another level, I have seen decidedly good (probably better than the most upvoted) answers without as much points because they were on the bottom of the list (or on the next page).

Comment: Aw, what's the fun in that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so is just like upvotes in mSOFU

Comment: I think that the very first votes affects the next ones.

Comment: @ilhan Yes, seeing the current vote count might cause some to pause, to try to account for why other's opinions might differ from my own, but I don't think that we're all cattle, blindly clicking without thinking.

Comment: @Michael You'd be surprised http://www.ted.com/talks/dan_ariely_asks_are_we_in_control_of_our_own_decisions.html

Comment: @Michael, they teach it in Statistics field, they are really biased.

Answer (score 0):

**Showing it probably does influence subsequent voters, but that's not entirely a negative.**

Sure, if those voters blindly fall in line, that's a bad thing.

On the other hand, if all 604 of the votes on a question are in favor of something you were about vote down, or flag as offensive, those votes may help you second guess yourself long enough to read further into the comments and realize that a "woodcock" is a totally legitimate thing to ask about on the Birds StackExchange.

Individuals in smart, analytical communities benefit from the additional information provided by the rest of the hive, just as long as they don't lose sight of the fact that sometimes, rarely, everyone else is wrong.