# lost rep on area51 'off-topic' vote?

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, area-51

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2912/persian-information-technology-and-computer/3966#3966

The only vote I see is a 'great off-topic' vote, but my profile shows a red box.

Comment: Are you sure you lost rep?  I've tried my hand at a few off-topic questions and they all show red boxes, but they actually *add* reputation.  It's just a weird colouring scheme...

Comment: Oh, hmm. Sure enough. No - sign. OK, fooled me.

Comment: Those boxes should have been changed to blue.  This has been fixed.

Comment: @David sorry, but I'm still seeing red boxes for off-topic votes

Comment: @Tobias Fixed now.  We had fixed it on the user profile page but missed the recent activity page

Answer (score 2):

`[status-we-don't-need-this-question-bumped-anymore-hopefully]`

Answer (score 0):

I also find the green/red for on-/off-topic votes [confusing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52266/voting-on-area51-is-very-biased/52267#52267).

But it looks like some of it (on the proposal page) has changed with the new voting (on-topic is now green, off-topic is blue, and bad is red), which is weird that green isn't the opposite of red.

Comment: Ah, I see you're talking about the profile page *only*.  I've not gotten any off-topic votes since the reset.