# Area51 off-topic reputation color

Tags: bug, voting, area-51, user-interface, recent-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [lost rep on area51 ‘off-topic’ vote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52633/lost-rep-on-area51-off-topic-vote)

Coming from the other sites in the trilogy, I'm trained that a green background means a positive reputation change, and a red background means a negative one. Currently on the recent activity page, if I get an off-topic vote (+5 rep), I see a red box and my heart skips a beat as I think of how to fix my mistake.

Surely I'm not the only one?

Looking around, [I guess I'm not the only one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52633/lost-rep-on-area51-off-topic-vote). That question says it's been fixed, but I'd say that's not the case yet for the recent activity page.