# Area 51: A haven for trolls?

Tags: discussion, area-51

Because Area 51 encourages off-topic questions, and users receive rep when their questions are voted off-topic, have we created a haven for trolls? A user could post countless absurd questions throughout the site and rapidly rise to 10K status. **Are these the people we want to trust with semi-mod powers?**

(I am not posting specific examples because I don't want to a) feed the trolls, and b) single anyone out)

---

**More thoughts:**

A good off-topic question is one that is *almost* on topic. These are useful, and posting them and voting on them should be encouraged. There are lots of bad questions that are *obviously* off-topic. It's very easy to write bad questions, and they are easily identified. I am concerned that lots of overtly bad questions will be posted, and these will get lots of votes. I don't think this is helpful, and has the side effect of elevating the users who post them.

Comment: voting will change today, you will have the Meh vote for trollish questions, or you can not vote on them at all, the best medicine for troll fever is to ignore it

Comment: This is a non-problem; you can vote a question for deletion. It's a hypothetical problem, too; while I have seen numerous spam proposals, I have seen very few overtly bad questions.

Comment: Hehe, this is funny: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3767/boxedusers-meta-stackoverflow-com

Comment: @Jinguy - Rich B and Evan Carroll are in the same place at the same time. This could get interesting!

Comment: So are 3 million other users. This could be less than interesting indeed. @jon

Answer (score 14):

Off-topic question submissions *are important* to determine the boundaries of the proposed site.  You don't know what you are unless you know what you aren't.  I actually find it a lot **harder** to think of good off-topic questions than good on-topic questions.

If the questions are *literally* trolls - as in, they have *nothing* to do with the site, as opposed to just tip-toeing on the boundary - then they shouldn't be voted off-topic, they should be deleted.  If people are giving them off-topic votes instead, then there needs to be some better education with respect to how votes should be issued.

I'm only following 3 proposals right now, but I really haven't seen that many troll questions.  Actually, I don't think I've seen *any*.  So I don't think it's really that big a problem, at least not on all proposals.

Answer (score 5):

If you see a user posting absurd questions, flag those questions as spam.

Comment: Agreed, but most questions are not blatantly absurd and/or trollish, they're perfectly legitimate on-topic or off-topic (but plausible) questions.

Comment: @Massimo: Then what's the problem? Vote on the content, not on who is posting.

Answer (score 2):

With the interface changes and changes to the voting system, posting silly or trivial questions will gain you little-to-no reputation. I'll post more about the changes as soon as we work out some of the details.

Answer (score 2):

A good troll isn't immediately recognizable as a troll. That's how they draw people in, get them to respond, sate that need for attention.

...And, IMHO, *these* are the sorts of questions you want to identify early on. Because they *won't* be dealt with effectively by the community after the site goes live - enough people will take them seriously to keep them open, or at least make them into centers of controversy. See "Boat programming", "Tabs vs. Spaces", "Why has [human society] [produced some outcome]?", etc. in the context of SO... These are not as easy to pull off - and I'm never *quite* sure if the individuals posting them are intentionally trolling or merely unable to grasp the purpose of the site. They're like Edward Norton's character in "The Score"...

So no, I don't think A51 is a "haven for trolls". Effective trolling is hard. It's the *blatantly* bad questions that are, as you note, easy to write and easy to vote on. But the voting system is changing anyway, so who knows what this'll end up looking like...

Answer (score 0):

Agreed.

That's why I'm proposing to decouple on-/off-topic status from question score.

[Proposal for a new voting system on Area 51 [Now with PICTURES!]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52501/proposal-for-a-new-voting-system-on-area-51)

Comment: One more post like that and I'll believe you are a spam robot advertising his product/question.

Comment: The problem is attracting some attention in the total chaos the new voting rules are going to create :-p

Comment: Then you should have done that earlier. If it is planned to release this afternoon, it is already programmed and they probably won't change now.

Comment: They announced the change **yesterday**, there really has not been so much time to do anything about that.

Comment: Also, asking for some feedback *before* announcing the change would have been a lot nicer...

Answer (score 0):

Asking a silly question is easy, but brings you no reputation in itself.

People to blame are more the ones voting for them. If a trolling question raises 10 votes and no delete, the problem is not the one who asked the question as much as the other people.

Comment: That may be so, but we can't really change those people.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with this question. There seem to be a handful of people (<= 10) who seem to be dedicated trolls either proposing preposterous Q&As or questions or voting down questions without any clear explanation.

So my answer to your question is **Yes**.

Comment: Link it, or it didn't happen.

Comment: @Ladybug Killer - I find your lack of faith *disturbing*. But OK, here's some examples of troll Q&As:
 * http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/17286/bikesheds
 * http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/16784/chuck-norris
 * http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/16368/flamewars
 * http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/16383/trolling

That last one is **all about trolling!** Just look through the closed list about 60% are duplicates (not trolling) and about 30% are troll suggestions.