# Area 51 questions are randomized every time I click to the next page

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

When you click on page 2 of the questions, you get a newly randomized list - including repeats from page 1. This makes it nearly impossible to view all questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be fixed now.  We're seeding the randomizer per-user, so you should see a stable sort until more posts get added.

Answer (score 0):

This is [intentional](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52168/how-can-we-get-better-quality-on-and-off-topic-questions-in-our-site-proposals/52172#52172), for the default sort order. You can sort using the "newest" tab if you would like to sift through every post.